# sheet_name.calculate doesn't update formulae but shift+f9 does update?

Tags: excel, vba

I am automating a sheet and within vba I call:

```
sheet_name.calculate
```

The problem is this doesn't appear to be updating some of my cells which depend on API calls to financial addins. They all still contain `#VALUE!` However, if I press "shift + f9" on the same sheet then all the cells containing `#VALUE!` suddenly refresh and contain correct numerical values.

Why isn't .calculate doing this?

(My calculation update settings are set to "manual" - this has been decided as I don't want automatic updates, only when my code calls .calculate)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Application.CalculateFull
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194064.aspx

If that doesn't work maybe this will help - it ensures all dependencies are rebuilt

```
Application.CalculateFullRebuild
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822609.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have not personally discovered any difference between worksheets("SheetName").Calculate and shift-f9 - but it may be worth trying this:

```
Worksheets("SheetName").EnableCalculation=False
Worksheets("SheetName").EnableCalculation=True
Worksheets("SheetName").Calculate
```

This forces a full calculation of the worksheet as opposed to a recalculate.

Comment: This was bugging me for an hour sometimes it used to calculate sometimes it didn't but this code ensured it calculates everytime :) Really helpful. Thanks